# AbstractTableModel setValueAt not firing upon Jbutton Click

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel

I have a custom TableModel that extends the AbstractTableModel.

```
public class IndicatorPropertyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
```

The setValueAt function I wrote fires appropriately in cases when you type a new value into the editable cell and then move on to another cell. The problem I am having is that for the last editable cell the user will immediately click a JButton to continue. This does not trigger the setValueAt function thus not saving the data. Is there a good way to ensure that this value is always stored when a user immediately hits a button after editing a cell? setValueAt function below for reference if needed.

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    if (value == null)
        return;
    if (col == 0) {
        //this.indicatorArguments[row].setIsSelected(value);
    } else if (col == 2) {
        this.indicatorArguments[row].setValue(value);
    }
    this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your button is outside the table.

In the event listener or action of your button you would need a reference to the table. This table you could then ask whether [isEditing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#isEditing%28%29) returns true. Then you would [get the current editor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getCellEditor%28%29) and after validating the last input value either call [stopCellEditing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#stopCellEditing%28%29) to commit the value or [cancelCellEditing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/CellEditor.html#cancelCellEditing%28%29) to undo the value.

In short:

```
if(table.isEditing()){
  table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
}
```

would always commit not yet entered values.

Comment: Your assumption was correct, the button was outside of the table. The code provided works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the table is editing requires you to add code to all buttons on your GUI.

You may be able to use a simple one line solution that avoids this. Check out [Table Stop Editing](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/).